# Get count of row and sum group by quarter of date, if another column doesnt exits a value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have some sample data:

```
Date              Status       OfferNum        Amount
------------------------------------------------------
2016/10/30      -   1      -     2000      -  1000,00
2016/08/25      -   0      -     2000      -  1100,00
2016/07/12      -   0      -     2001      -  1200,00
2016/08/30      -   0      -     2001      -  1300,00
2016/07/12      -   1      -     2002      -  1400,00
2016/08/30      -   1      -     2002      -  1500,00
2016/08/30      -   1      -     2003      -  1600,00
```

I don't want to count if one of `offerNum` status value has 1 and in the same quarter(if it has 1 but it isnt same quarter it has to be count). But I want to sum all of the amount(it isnt depends status column)

Here is the result that I want:

```
Quarter   Count                          TotalAmount
----------------------------------------------------
2016/Q3     2 (offerNum 2002 and 2003)      8100,00
2016/Q4     1 (offerNum 2000)               1000,00
```

Here is the sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eac9d

Comment: How do you get 8100 by adding offernum 2002 and 2003?

Comment: it is all amount of 2016/Q3 quarter, not just 2002 and 2003.

Comment: still you are getting 8000 rite? How 8100?

Comment: My bad in your fiddle, you have provided last value as 1500 so it is getting 8000, probably copy-paste mistake

Comment: Your example does not provide negative test case, can you add that value as well?

Comment: there is no data as negative, it is just 1 and 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to compute the status of each `offer`, then compute the final result aggregated by quarter. Notice that the `GROUP BY` year is important, otherwise result will contain data coming from the same quarter of the previous years.

```
--
-- Answer updated according to SQL Fiddle.
-- Check: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/709ff/9
--
WITH offers AS
(
    SELECT
        CONCAT(DATEPART(yy, date), '/Q', DATEPART(qq, date)) AS Quarter,
        offer,
        MAX(status) AS status,
        SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount
    FROM temp
    GROUP BY
        DATEPART(yy, date),
        DATEPART(qq, date),
        offer
)
SELECT
    Quarter,
    SUM(status) AS Count,
    SUM(TotalAmount) AS TotalAmount
FROM offers
GROUP BY Quarter
```

Comment: i edited. Now it's clear. But in your code SUM(status)  counts all status. i want only 1 if there is two or more in same offerNum

Comment: If you change Sum(durum) as Count by COUNT(distinct durum) AS [Count] I guess you get what are you loocking for.

Comment: No. it counts 1 and 0 value in each offerNum.  if these 1's repeat for one offerNum twice or more it has count 1

Comment: You're welcome @VedatKaraağaç. Happy coding and I just upvoted your post.

Answer (score 0):

Are you locking for this:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(DATEPART(yy, [date]), '/Q', DATEPART(qq, [date])) AS Quarter,
    COUNT(case [status] when  1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Count],
    SUM([Amount]) AS TotalAmount
  FROM [dbo].[temp]
  group by  DATEPART(yy, [date]), DATEPART(qq, [date])
```

Comment: i want only status column 1's count. But if these 1's repeat for one offerNum twice or more it  has count 1. in your code it counts 1 and 0 values in each offerNum

Comment: Thanks Mincong Huang for the right datepart clausules... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can query like this

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT
    concat(YEAR(date), '/Q', DATEPART(q, date)) AS q,
    amount,
    SUM(status) OVER (PARTITION BY concat(YEAR(date), '/Q', DATEPART(q, date))) AS OfferStatusSum,
    status
FROM temp)
SELECT
    q, COUNT(DISTINCT status),
    SUM(CASE WHEN OfferStatusSum >= 1 THEN amount
        ELSE 0
    END)
FROM cte
GROUP BY q
```

Comment: you missed count value ? :)

Comment: Added count as well - Updated code, you can modify that :)