# SQL query to return quarterly dates from list of dates

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-query-store

Can someone help me with the SQL query? I have a table with has data like this

**Periodtable**:

```
ID
StartDate
EndDate
```

The data will look like this:

```
1 1/3/2017 2/2/2017
2 2/3/2017 3/2/2017
3 3/3/2017 4/2/207
4 4/3/2017 5/2/2017
5 5/3/2017 6/2/2017
6 6/3/2017 7/2/2017
7 7/3/2017 8/2/2017
8 8/3/2017 9/2/2017
9 9/3/2017 10/2/2017
```

...

I want to write a SQL query which returns the following 3 columns:

```
9,8,7 | 7/3/2017 | 10/2/2017
6,5,4 | 4/3/2017 | 7/2/2017
3,2,1 | 1/3/2017 | 4/2/2017
```

Comment: quarterly ? you mean to group the rows for every three months based on start date and end date ?

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @RohitPadma yes

Comment: @user1447718, please make an effort to investigate answers for yourself before posting a question. These kinds of questions have been asked and answered many times before. An example that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791065/get-count-of-row-and-sum-group-by-quarter-of-date-if-another-column-doesnt-exit/39791207#39791207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL below using the xml path trick to fold the Id's into a list, grouped by quarter.

```
select 
stuff(
 (select concat(',',tid.ID)
  from PeriodTable tid
  where datepart(quarter,tid.Startdate) = datepart(quarter,t.Startdate)
    and datepart(year,tid.Startdate) = datepart(year,t.Startdate)
  for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
 ,1,1,'') IdList,
min(StartDate) as FirstStartDate, max(EndDate) as LastEndDate
from PeriodTable t
group by datepart(year,Startdate), datepart(quarter,Startdate)
order by FirstStartDate;
```

Or this variation of the method that uses a CROSS APPLY:

```
select 
stuff(max(Ids),1,1,'') as IdList, min(StartDate) as FirstStartDate, max(EndDate) as LastEndDate
from PeriodTable t
cross apply (
   select concat(',',tid.ID)
   from PeriodTable tid
   where datepart(quarter,tid.Startdate) = datepart(quarter,t.Startdate)
     and datepart(year,tid.Startdate) = datepart(year,t.Startdate)
   for xml path('')) List(Ids)
group by datepart(year,Startdate), datepart(quarter,Startdate)
order by FirstStartDate;
```

Try it [here on rextester](http://rextester.com/DZXXX65667)